# How RPM found conflict during installation?

Tags: centos, rpm

I was building an rpm. I ran rpm -ivh X.rpm but got an error **file /lib/modules/abc conflicts with file from package Y.**
My question is how rpm check the conflicts?
can I use all these conflicts in the spec file so I don't get all these conflict.

Answer (score 2):

`rpm` keeps track of all files installed by all `rpm` packages. Two packages **cannot** provide the same file or folder. So you just must make sure that all your packages provide a complete distinct set of files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

Follow guidelines for RPM specs, like the [Fedora packaging guidelines regarding Versioning](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Versioning/).

There is no one general answer to how to resolve this. Possibly you are providing an upgrade. Or how you packaged it steps on other files and you need to split it out differently following existing conventions. Provide details - the entire spec file - if you want specifics.

Update the `Version:` and `Release:` tags, and provide a corresponding changelog entry. Name-Version-Release needs to be newer than any package you may be replacing. Replacing is a tricky thing, several add-on repos don't do it at all.

Use yum (or dnf) for all package installs. It checks the transaction, and can dependency solve to show you what happens to other packages.